# Test fails with "The element reference is stale" in Firefox but same code passes in chrome

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox

I am receiving the below error when running my test in firefox.

`"OpenQA.Selenium.StaleElementReferenceException : The element reference of <tr class="rgNoRecords"> is stale; either the element is no longer attached to the DOM, it is not in the current frame context, or the document has been refreshed"`

The same code works in chrome.

It fails in this block of code:

```
public static string GetElementTextByXPath(string XPath, string expectedText = null)
    {
      string elementNotFound = FrameworkSettings.msgElementNotFound;


      if (IsElementPresentByXpath_Continue(XPath))
      {

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Int32.Parse(FrameworkSettings.ImplicitWaitTimeout_Long)));

        wait.Until((d) => { return d.FindElement(By.XPath(XPath)); });

        ElementScrollIntoViewByXPath(XPath);

        OutlineSelectedElement(driver.FindElement(By.XPath(XPath)), "get");



        if (expectedText == null)
        {

          wait.Until((d) => { return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(d.FindElement(By.XPath(XPath)).Text); });
        }
        else
        {

          wait.Until((d) => { return d.FindElement(By.XPath(XPath)).Text == expectedText; });
        }

        return driver.FindElement(By.XPath(XPath)).Text;
      }
      else
      {
        return elementNotFound;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Comment: Hi Christine, Its the below line  OutlineSelectedElement(driver.FindElement(By.XPath(XPath)), "get");